# How do I tell robocopy to ignore timestamps?

Tags: windows, command-line, robocopy

I have two copies of my Music directory on separate drives. One is a thumb drive that I carry around with me so I can listen to whatever whenever. Initially I copied this directory to the thumbdrive using robocopy. I'm not sure the exact parameters I used, but it was probably:

```
robocopy D:\Music F:\Music /E /MIR
```

Now the drives are out of sync, so I want to robocopy again. However, for some weird reason, the timestamps are off on all the files by one hour. So when I try to run the command above, it starts copying every single file from D:\Music to F:\Music because it is newer.

How do I tell robocopy to ignore these timestamps and just copy files with different filenames, or those that have changed in some other significant way (such as the artist or genre info or something)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy ONLY those files that are not in the destination?](http://superuser.com/questions/466090/how-to-copy-only-those-files-that-are-not-in-the-destination)

Comment: @Izam that's pretty close but I'd like for it to copy files if something about the files has changed other than timestamp.

Comment: Have you tried `/DST` switch?

Comment: @MCND that's exactly what I needed! You should post that as the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To handle one hour differences in environments where [DST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) is active, `robocopy` includes since version XP026 (included in downloadable Robocopy GUI) or XP027 (included in Windows Vista) a `/DST` switch to *`"Compensate for one-hour DST time differences"`*